# What may be the reason of error `exception in thread "main"` happened in Apache IoTDB?

Tags: time-series, apache-iotdb, iotdb

I set up a cluster using Apache IoTDB with one ConfigNode and three DataNodes. When I try to execute this cluster system, I received an error: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/antlr/v4/runtime/misc/ParseCancellationException`. Why did this problem occur and how should I deal with it?

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the current number of `lib` in Apache IoTDB is the same as the number when you first downloaded it. It is recommended to delete the `lib` folders and re-import it.